# Cannot create instance of MainViewModel - has no zero argument constructor with Compose Hilt

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

Using Jetpack Compose to build small Room database app. I keep getting error:

```
Cannot create an instance of class com.learning.kotlinreadexstingroomdb.MainViewModel
...
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.learning.kotlinreadexstingroomdb.MainViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
```

#### MainActivity.kt

```
package com.learning.kotlinreadexstingroomdb

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.collectAsState
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import com.learning.kotlinreadexstingroomdb.ui.theme.KotlinReadExstingRoomDBTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            KotlinReadExstingRoomDBTheme {
                MyApp()
            }
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun MyApp() {
        val result by mainViewModel.readAll.collectAsState(initial= emptyList())

        Column(
            modifier = androidx.compose.ui.Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            if (result.isNotEmpty()) {
                Text(
                    //text = person.name,
                    text = "There is Data!",
                    fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.h4.fontSize
                )
            } else {
                Text(
                    text = "Empty Database",
                    fontSize = MaterialTheme.typography.h4.fontSize
                )
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### MainViewModel.kt

```
package com.learning.kotlinreadexstingroomdb

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.learning.kotlinreadexstingroomdb.data.PersonRepository
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel
@Inject
constructor(personRepository: PersonRepository): ViewModel(){
    val readAll = personRepository.readAll
}
```

#### build.gradle (:app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'                                            
}
...
dependencies {

    def room_version = "2.4.1"                                              
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version")              
    annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")        

    def dagger_hilt_version = "2.40.5"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$dagger_hilt_version"    
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$dagger_hilt_version"             

    def compose_version = "1.0.5"                                           
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"

}
```

I feel like I've tried everything I could find on the web, but nothing fixes it.

Note: Code is based on: [Pre-Populate ROOM Database with Already Loaded Data | Android Studio Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pe28WeQ0VCc)

Comment: You seems using Hilt, your activity should be annotated with `@dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint`, also you need to have application class annotated with `@dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp`. More about Hilt integration can be found in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android)

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I added `@dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint` but that doesn't fix it.  I like the idea of putting `@HiltAndroidApp` somewhere, but I'm not sure I understand where?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you annotate your Application class to initialise Hilt

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class App : Application()
```

Your Application class needs to be registered in the manifest if it isn't already.

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        ... />
```

You also need to annotate your activities and fragments so that Hilt can inject into them.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity
```

Comment: I like where you're going with this, but when I change `private val...` to `hiltViewModel()`, it highlights hiltViewModel in red and says `Unresolved reference: hiltViewModel`.  What am I missing?

Comment: @SqueezeOJ I've updated my answer to remove hiltViewModel() as that's only when using compose, I've also added some other things to check.

Comment: I hate to admit it, but this may still be over my head!  I'm going to back-up a bit and try a simpler non-hilt Room database.

Answer (score 1):

Add `@AndroidEntryPoint` annotation in main activity

```
@AndroidEntryPoint // this line 
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val mainViewModel: MainViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            KotlinReadExstingRoomDBTheme {
                MyApp()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and get the following error: `public final class MainActivity extends androidx.activity.ComponentActivity {
             ^
  Expected @AndroidEntryPoint to have a value. Did you forget to apply the Gradle Plugin? (dagger.hilt.android.plugin)`